# Element has to reload when I scroll on mobile

Tags: html, css

I have built a donate page with a header (the picture currently inserted in the header is a generic placeholder). When I load this page on an iPhone or Android, it looks great at first. But when I scroll down to view the rest of the page and then scroll back up, the header is missing for a second, and then it appears again as originally rendered.

I want to make it so that when I scroll away from the header it stays there and doesn't have to reload when I scroll back up to it.

Here is the code:

```css
.container_12 {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 1200px;
    }

       #student_dashboard .container_12 .grid_12 {
         width: 100%;
        }
        .container_12 .grid_12 {
          width: 90.5%;
        }
         .grid_1, .grid_2, .grid_3, .grid_4, .grid_5, .grid_6, .grid_7, .grid_8, .grid_9, .grid_10, .grid_11, .grid_12 {
               display: inline;
               float: left;
               position: relative;
               margin-left: 15.0px;
               margin-right: 15.0px;
         }
         header #logo {
          display: inline-block;
          float: left;
         }
         img {
           vertical-align: middle;
           display: block;
           float: none;
           margin: 0 auto;
          }
          img {
            border: 0;
          }
```

```html
<body id="student_dashboard">
            <form id="form1" runat="server">
              <div id="custom_bg"><img src='<%= Page.ResolveClientUrl("~/secure-image/" + idBGImage) %>'></div>
        <header>
      <div class="container_12">
       <div class="grid_12">
                    <div id="logo"><img src='<%= Page.ResolveClientUrl("~/secure-image/" + idLogo)%>' width="100" height="100"></div>
                    <h1 id="welcome">Welcome to <span id="spanName" runat="server"></span> Fundraising page</h1>
                </div>
      </div>
        </header>
        <div class="clearfix"></div>
        <div id="content">  
            <div class="container_12">
                <div class="wrapper">

                    <div class="grid_4">
                        <div><img src='<%= Page.ResolveClientUrl("~/secure-image/" + idImage)%>' class="rounded-image-corners" /></div>
                        <div class="name"><span id="spanNameMain" runat="server"></span></div>
                        <blockquote >Please help me reach my fundraising goal! Thank you so much!
                        </blockquote>
                    </div>
                    <div class="grid_8">
                      <div class="grid_8">
                        <div class="padding">
                          <p>Welcome to my fundraiser! Thank you for being willing to participate and help me and my team! You can see how my team is doing with our fundraising goal by checking the gauge at the bottom of this page. Remember, each dollar counts!</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="grid_8">
                      <div class="padding">
                            <h3>Donate</h3>
                            <p>Make a direct donation to my fundraising account by clicking the "Donate" button below.</p>
                            <br><br>
                       </div>
                      
                            <div id="thermo2" class="thermometer horizontal">
                                <div class="track">
                                    <div class="goal">
                                        <div class="amount"> 1000000 </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="progressbar">
                                        <div class="amount">354680 </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>  

                       <div class="padding" id="paddingbtn">              
                          <asp:ImageButton ID="btnImageDonate" runat="server"  ImageURL="~/Images/btndonate.png"  />
                       </div>  
                    </div>  
                    </div>
                    </div>
                            
                    </div> 
            </div>    
        </div>
        <div class="clearfix"></div>

        </form>
    </body>
```

Comment: could you at least post the computed CSS properties of the image?

Comment: No problem. give me a second.

Comment: It is probably an optimisation made by the browser. I dont think css will change anything to that

Comment: Yeah, it seems to happen on all browsers on a mobile device.

Comment: It looks like a repainting that the browser does on scroll. If you try it on a more performant device, the side effects might be lessened.
Overall, you should reduce the ammount of processing your page requires, if possible, to make it performant in a wider spectrum of scenarios

Answer (score 0):

This is an optimization issue.  Use the picture tag in your html to solve it.  Picture loads different size images depending on the screen size.

```
<picture>
  <source srcset="img/hero_landscape.png" media="(max-width: 480px)" />
  <img src="img/hero_pc.png" alt="Default Image" width="710" height="200"> 
</picture>
```

[Info and examples on picture](http://html5hub.com/html5-picture-element/)